# How to include local settings in an .htaccess file that is shared between different servers?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mirror-site

I am running a small network of web servers (Apache 2.2/2.4) using essentially the same CGI infrastructure on different machines (and under different domains). The function of each site depends on rather lengthy *.htacces* files with only minor differences (site names, file locations, URL bases, etc). To reduce the need for redundant edits I have to somehow synchronize the *.htaccess* files among the servers despite the minor differences.

When it comes to the CGI source code, I can do this rather easily using SVN and *Makefile*. In particular, here I have a *Makefile* distributed along with the code via SVN and a non-versioned *Makefile.local* that is included by the *Makefile* and defines the local settings. I'd really like to do something similar with the *.htaccess* files, but I am unaware of a way to include local settings.

Is it possible to "load" local settings into an *.htaccess* file, may it be as an "include" from another file or as a way to define local environment variables elsewhere? Or is there some other way how this is usually handled for *.htaccess* files?

Many thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.